# Why can I not set deserializer in consumer factory?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

everybody.

```
package kitchen;

import entity.Order;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PizzaKitchenApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PizzaKitchenApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Order> consumerFactory(){
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();

        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "com.pizzapool");

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configs, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(Order.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Order> orderConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory(){
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Order> containerFactory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();

        containerFactory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        containerFactory.setMessageConverter(new JsonMessageConverter());

        return containerFactory;
    }
}
```

It's my consumer config. When I'm running the application i see in console:

```
value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

But I set value deserializer to JsonDeserializer. I tried to set trough configuration map. In both cases it doesn't work. When I received the message I have:

```
org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [public void kitchen.service.KafkaOrderMessagingService.handle(entity.Order) throws javax.jms.JMSException]
Bean [kitchen.service.KafkaOrderMessagingService@13183edf]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [java.lang.String] to [entity.Order] for GenericMessage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#record-listener):

> This mechanism requires an @EnableKafka annotation on one of your @Configuration classes and a listener container factory, which is used to configure the underlying ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer. **By default, a bean with name kafkaListenerContainerFactory is expected.**

Your bean is named `orderConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory`.

You can use this default name or specify custom bean's name in the listener with

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "test", containerFactory = "orderConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
```

The `containerFactory` is useful also when you need multiple different factories.